# Override _prepareSpecificInformation method of \Magento\Payment\Block\Info\Cc class

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I want to override **_prepareSpecificInformation** method of the  ***Magento\Payment\Block\Info\Cc*** class

**This is Core class.**

*vendor/magento/module-payment/Block/Info/Cc.php*

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Payment\Block\Info;

/**
 * Credit card generic payment info
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Cc extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Info
{
  
protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
{
    if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation) {
        return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
    }
    $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
    $data = [];
    if ($ccType = $this->getCcTypeName()) {
        $data[(string)__('Credit Card Type')] = $ccType;
    }
    if ($this->getInfo()->getCcLast4()) {
        $data[(string)__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcLast4());
    }

    if (!$this->getIsSecureMode()) {
        if ($ccSsIssue = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsIssue()) {
            $data[(string)__('Switch/Solo/Maestro Issue Number')] = $ccSsIssue;
        }
        $year = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsStartYear();
        $month = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsStartMonth();
        if ($year && $month) {
            $data[(string)__('Switch/Solo/Maestro Start Date')] = $this->_formatCardDate($year, $month);
        }
    }
    return $transport->setData(array_merge($data, $transport->getData()));
}
```

Following is what I have done.

**Muk/OrderEmail/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Payment\Block\Info\Cc" type="Muk\OrderEmail\Block\Info\Cc"/>
</config>
```

**My custom class**

**app/code/Muk/OrderEmail/Block/Info/Cc.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Muk\OrderEmail\Block\Info;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Cc extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Info\Cc
{
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Config $paymentConfig,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $paymentConfig, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare credit card related payment info
     *
     * @param DataObject|array $transport
     * @return DataObject
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
    {
        if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation) {
            return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
        }
        $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
        $data = [];
        if ($ccType = $this->getCcTypeName()) {
            $data[(string)__('Credit Card Type')] = $ccType;
        }
        if ($this->getInfo()->getCcLast4()) {
            $data[(string)__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcLast4());
        }
        
        // Custom information
        if ($ccType = $this->getCcTypeName()) {
            $data[(string)__('Name on the Card:')] = $this->getInfo()->getCcOwner();
        }
        // End Custom information
        
        if (!$this->getIsSecureMode()) {
            if ($ccSsIssue = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsIssue()) {
                $data[(string)__('Switch/Solo/Maestro Issue Number')] = $ccSsIssue;
            }
            $year = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsStartYear();
            $month = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsStartMonth();
            if ($year && $month) {
                $data[(string)__('Switch/Solo/Maestro Start Date')] = $this->_formatCardDate($year, $month);
            }
        }
        return $transport->setData(array_merge($data, $transport->getData()));
    }
}
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Muk_OrderEmail">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Payment"/>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Muk_OrderEmail',
    __DIR__
);
```

But this override is not working for me.

Comment: I think using preferences for this class isn't a good way. Did you try to use the plugin for the getSpecificInformation() yet? I think it's better

Comment: I may use Plugin but still using preference it is not working

Comment: There isn't any problem with the structures as the codes. Can you try to place a debug inside your preference to ensure that it ran into it already?

Comment: @JamesDinh if I do echo 'hello'; exit; in the protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null) the control does not reaches here.

Comment: So that proves your preference hasn't been applied yet. Can you check whether your module available and enabled properly? But for customizing info block type of payment. You can override infoBlockType property of the payment method and define your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I was overriding a wrong file. Because the **\Magento\Payment\Block\Info\Cc** was already overridden by a custom module.

After correcting the preference it worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="VendorName\Paymetric\Block\Xiintercept\Info\Iframe" type="Muk\OrderEmail\Block\Info\Cc"/>
</config>
```

Comment: I was also making mistake and overriding other parent class. After adding preference for actual class it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating in this, we have found solution for this. You can not override _prepareSpecificInformation method directly because this method is overided into another class that name is Magento\Paypal\Block\Payment\Info.

You have to override this class into custom module than you can do whatever changes into function that you want do.

Please refer this content for more info:

https://itcruncher.blogspot.com/2020/11/override-preparespecificinformation.html

If you like please give kund